# Saving PDF reading function result to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nlp, pypdf

I am trying to assign the result of my function to a variable when applied,but when i try to do print the assigned variable it comes out as None. how do i save and print out page_contents outside of the function? See code below:

```
def mpdf(pdf):
   pdfName = pdf
   read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfName)
   for i in range(read_pdf.getNumPages()):
       page = read_pdf.getPage(i)
       print ('Page No - ' +    str(1+read_pdf.getPageNumber(page)))
       page_content = page.extractText()
       print ((page_content))
df=mpdf('sample.pdf')
print(df)
Output>>>None
```

Comment: You never `return` anything from `mpdf`...

Answer (score 0):

Your function has to `return page_content`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere you need to `return` from within the function

```
def mpdf(pdf):
   pdfName = pdf
   read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfName)
   for i in range(read_pdf.getNumPages()):
       page = read_pdf.getPage(i)
       print ('Page No - ' +    str(1+read_pdf.getPageNumber(page)))
       page_content = page.extractText()
       print (page_content) # Do you need two parens?
       return page # or page_content
df=mpdf('sample.pdf')
print(df)
```

If you return the page, you have access to the whole page object and all its methods, as opposed to the result of the `extractText()` method.

Comment: This really helps, but if I do return page_content I only get one page of the pdf. I am trying to get the whole document.